# jQuery post pass and receive array

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, post

I have a node.js & Express app. In the front-end, I am passing an object that contains an array field with a jQuery post request:

```
var test = {
  'dob[]': [12, 01, 1999]
}

$.post("/test1", test, () => {});
```

In the backend, I am receiving the request with:

```
router.post("/test1", (req, res) => {
  console.log("test date of birth: " + req.body.dob);
  res.send("123");
})
```

The console.log shows the dob field is undefined.

We also tried

```
var test = {
  dob: [12, 01, 1999]
}

$.post("/test1", test, () => {});
```

And we got the same result. Our router is made with Express. Any ideas on how to pass and receive arrays as a field inside an object without putting all the array elements into separate fields? We also tried:

```
var test = {
  dob: JSON.stringify(["12", "01", "1999"])
}
```

But it just passes the array as a string (with the square brackets being part of the strings as well). How could we pass it as an array?

Comment: you can try body-parser libray for receving json data. https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: use this implementation: var test = {
  dob: [12, 01, 1999]
}

$.post("/test1", test, () => {});